# Chose correct firebase app type for the Ionic app

Tags: android, ios, firebase, ionic-framework, ionic3

When we go to the firebase console we can see below screen.Normally I create a `web` app when I need to use real time database on the firebase.But I have seen some Ionic apps are using Android and iOS app types.Can you tell me when to use which application type on firebase console?

If we use `Android` or `iOS` I cannot see below `config` section where we normally use with the real-time database and authentication use cases.How to get `config` details when we use `Android` and `iOS` app types? Hope we cannot use both `web` and other 2 types simultaneously with the single Ionic project.Am I right?

[image]

```
 var config = {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyAFbhJLwi0lgcvVCtspZt3jvHiXCUN2Okc",
    authDomain: "sandbox-e35ab.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://sandbox-e35ab.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "sandbox-e35ab",
    storageBucket: "sandbox-e35ab.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "605859521671"
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

With Firebase you will have a Project with many different apps.  Even apps of the same type (like 2 android apps, 2 ios apps and 3 web apps). After you're setup there's a `plus` icon on the main landing page for adding more apps.

> How to get config details when we use Android and iOS app types?

Click on the gear icon in the upper left and choose `project settings`.  That has your apps listed and you can  download plist or json files.  Android Studio has a Firebase tool that will download this for you.  Be sure to read the [getting started guides in the Firebase Docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup).